# HTML Editor for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, text-editor

Can anyone recommend an HTML editor for ASP.NET?

I'm not talking about a WYSIWYG editor, but one that will highlight elements and attributes like the Umbraco or other content management systems do.

So as someone is typing HTML it will highlight certain items to make it more readable.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express ?

Comment: I know visual studio does, I'm talking about a web based component that you can add to your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax hightlighting? I find [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) to be fantastic. It transforms a textarea

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try obout html editor. I am using it in my applications and they work like a charm.

[Obout.Ajax.UI Controls - HTML Editor - Editor control](http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use [MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/) if that helps at all?

Answer (score 0):

ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender  is best for this.

```
 <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" 
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
        <Toolbar> 
            <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
            <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
            <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
            <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
            <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
            <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
            <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
            <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
            <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
            <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
            <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
            <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
            <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
        </Toolbar>
    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

visit here for Demo: [HtmlEditorExtender Demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx)